# How to extract numbers of a nested list of tuples which exist in another list in python

Tags: python, list, tuples, nested-lists

I have a nested list in python and want to extract some numbers of it. Each sublist contains tuples and each tuple has two numbers which first one is always `2`. I want to extract second number of tuples from sublists that second number of all their tuples exist in another list (`check_values`). this is my data:

```
points=[[(2, 12), (2, 11)], [(2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 0), (2, 2)],\
        [(2, 0), (2, 19), (2, 5)], [(2, 18), (2, 20)]]
check_values=[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 11, 17, 18, 20]
```

As my data shows only the second value of tuples from second (that are `3, 5, 0, 2`) and last (that are `18, 20`) sublists exist in `check_values`. So, my result should be:

```
extracted=[[3, 5, 0, 2], [18, 20]]
```

I tried the following but it was not successful:

```
extracted=[]
for i in points:
    for j in i:
        if j[1] in check_values:
            extracted.append (i)
```

I do appreciate any help in advance.

Comment: Dear @Guy, I got the answer but it should but `11` should not be there because both second values of first sublist does not exist in `check_values`. In fact, `12` is missing. For the third sublist also `19` is the missing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
extracted = []

# for each sublist...
for sublist in points:
    # get the second values of each tuple
    second_vals = [sec for fir, sec in sublist]

    # check if "all" of the values in `second_vals` are in `check_values`
    if all(val in check_values for val in second_vals):
        # store the `second_vals` if so
        extracted.append(second_vals)
```

to get

```
>>> extracted
[[3, 5, 0, 2], [18, 20]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Mustafa's answer is completely valid, here it goes another variant:

```py
# This extracts the second values that are in the check_values list
# That is: [[11], [3, 5, 0, 2], [0, 5], [18, 20]]
extracted = [ [pair[1] for pair in sublist if pair[1] in check_values] for sublist in points]

# The second step filters out those sublists whose size is different, i.e. not
# all second values are in the check_values list
extracted = [ x for i, x in enumerate(extracted) if len(x) == len(points[i]) ]
```

Finally we get:

```py
[[3, 5, 0, 2], [18, 20]]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here is another way for the same:**

```py
points=[[(2, 12), (2, 11)], [(2, 3), (2, 5), (2, 0), (2, 2)],\
        [(2, 0), (2, 19), (2, 5)], [(2, 18), (2, 20)]]
check_values=[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 10, 11, 17, 18, 20]

extracted_value=[]
def check_2nd_value(sublist:list):
    """
    This method will get the sublist and 
    check the availability of 2nd items of every tuple in check_value (given list)
    """
    # gets 2nd item of the tuples
    tple_item2 = [tple[1] for tple in sublist]
    # if the difference between two set is empty
    # then all values are available in 2nd list
    diff = set(tple_item2).difference(set(check_values))
    if diff:
        return 
    else:
        return tple_item2

# finding all the lists - for configured option
for sublist in points:
    found_items = check_2nd_value(sublist)
    # if found_items is not None then -> append the list
    if found_items:
        extracted_value.append(found_items)
```

**And the extracted values are:**

```py
print(extracted_value)
[[3, 5, 0, 2], [18, 20]]
```